# Swift Switch statement fails to match strings: What could cause this?

Tags: swift, switch-statement, watchkit, apple-watch

I have some code to determine the Series of an Apple Watch based on its [machine ID](https://gist.github.com/adamawolf/3048717). In all testing I've been able to do on real Apple Watches, it works as expected.

However, once out in the wild, it fails to match in some cases, and falls back on the `default` case. I added some logging to the `default` to show the see the `model` value that was passed in when it failed to match, to see if there were unexpected values being passed into the function.

To my surprise, the values that are being passed in seem to match, but it's still hitting the default case. For example `Watch3,4` is frequently being logged as the value of `model` that was passed in, which should match the case to produce *Series 3*, and does in my testing, but for some reason it's not always matching in my app once released. The same goes for many other model strings here.

Does it seem like there is something I'm missing here? Like the possibility of other non-visible characters ending up in the string I'm checking? Or something I'm missing about how `switch` statements work in Swift?

To be clear, it's not failing all the time. It works most of the time, but it sometimes fails even though logging shows the value passed in is an expected value that matches a non-default case.

Here's my code, minus the logging used for diagnosis:

```
import Foundation

func getWatchModel() -> String? {
    var size: size_t = 0
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", nil, &size, nil, 0)
    var machine = CChar()
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", &machine, &size, nil, 0)
    return String(cString: &machine, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
}

func getSeries(model: String) -> String {
    switch model {
    case "Watch2,3", "Watch2,4":
        return "Series 2"
    case "Watch2,6", "Watch2,7":
        return "Series 1"
    case "Watch3,1", "Watch3,2", "Watch3,3", "Watch3,4":
        return "Series 3"
    case "Watch4,1", "Watch4,2", "Watch4,3", "Watch4,4":
        return "Series 4"
    case "Watch5,1", "Watch5,2", "Watch5,3", "Watch5,4":
        return "Series 5"
    default:
        return "Unknown Series"
    }
}

let series: String?

if let model = getWatchModel() {
    series = getSeries(model: model)
} else {
    series = nil
}

print(series ?? "Apple Watch machine ID could not be determined")
```

Comment: Btw that could be written as just `let series = getWatchModel().map(getSeries(model:)`. I would recommend you try logging the utf8 view, to see if there's any sneaky characters (things that look like commas but aren't, zero width joiners, etc.).

Comment: Cool, I mostly just added that for illustrative purposes instead to show how I'm using the value, but I appreciate the comment as I wasn't familiar with that way to write it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem is actually in your `getWatchModel` method, specifically in the line:

```swift
var machine = CChar()
```

This allocates a single byte. You need to allocate `size` bytes. 
Here's one way of doing it:

```swift
    func getWatchModel() -> String? {
        var size: size_t = 0
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", nil, &size, nil, 0)
        var machine = [CChar](repeating: 0, count: size)
        sysctlbyname("hw.machine", &machine, &size, nil, 0)
        return String(cString: machine, encoding: .utf8)
    }
```

I suspect this lead to the `String` containing garbage. I'm actually surprised you did not see any crashes.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with C, so thanks for the detailed breakdown. The string output I was getting looked fine, but obviously the way it looks is not the whole story with strings, so I'll give this a try and also spend some time learning more about the C concepts behind this.

Comment: I rolled out this change in an update and it's now working as expected.